# how to compare values from 2 index of elastic store in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, compare, kibana, elastic-map-reduce, kibana-4

I have 2 indices in my elasticsearch store.
Now in Kibana visualisation, i have to search for a count of docs in index B where "col_A" of indexA is equal to "col_H" of IndexB.
Is this possible in kibana?
If so please help me with the queries.
TIA folks.